# Can I mention dependencies with latest in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I see that my friend are using `latest` in dependencies as follows

`{
  "dependencies": {
    "somemodule": "latest"
  }
}`

I feels that this is kind of dangerous when I deploy my application in different environments `qa -> stage -> production`, since this pulls latest version of dependency module always.

And how about if i have `package-lock.json` in my application directory. Will it help to put same version of dependency modules as like as my local environment in all different environment

Can anyone help me to understand good and bad on this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a subjective situation and completely depends on your development and QA process.  If you upgrade often and know exactly what breaking changes may happen then go for it.

**Otherwise** stick with one version until you want to upgrade, do some research on that version and implement accordingly.

Comment: can package-lock.json lock my packages, if i use latest in dependencies list(package.json)
can you elaborate more?